# Error message Notice: Undefined variable while include function in php

Tags: php, scope

I have too separate PHP files:

1. add-new-module.php
2. _add-new-module.php

I' am using the function require_once `_add-new-module.php` in the `add-new-module.php` at the very top of the page. I have initialized the variable `$msg` into `_add-new-module.php` for some reason its still showing up error message as:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: msg in xxxxxxxxxxx/add-new-module.php on line 2
```

When echoing the variable `$msg` in `_add-new-module.php` it WORKS but when I try to echo the variable `$msg` in `add-new-module.php` it gives me above error. When I used `islet` on the variable `$msg` well it hides error message but doesn't show anything on the page.

I have also replaced include with `include_once`, `require_once` and `require`. Still no luck. I have also used global `$msg` hides the error message but doesn't seems to display the result.

Comment: No, I' am not using any Framework. I can confirm that both the files are being includes. I have tested with echo on both files and works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use global $msg; in add-new-module.php, just write it before echo $msg;

```
 global $msg;
 echo $msg;
```

if not working To Enable Global Variables Register_globals In PHP APACHE Server Php.ini

register_globals = On

if you want to turn it on within your page you can put this code at the begining of your code:

ini_set('register_globals', true);

otherwise enable register_globals via .htaccess:

1. Create an .htaccess in your virtual host's root directory
2. put the following code in it:

   //Override PHP settings. The first IfModule is
   //for Apache 1.3, the second for Apache 2.

   ```
    <IfModule mod_php4.c>
        php_value register_globals 1
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
        php_value register_globals 1
    </IfModule>

      php_flag register_globals 1
   ```

Comment: if not working To Enable Global Variables Register_globals In PHP APACHE Server Php.ini

Comment: Three options added, please try with configure htaccess or php.ini

Answer (score 0):

`$msg` is probably out of scope, try adding

```
global $msg;
```

to the page where it is used.

Comment: Sorry still doesn't work.

Comment: could you post the relevant portions of the two module files?